# Где можно накачать огромную кучу иконок?

Tags: android, дизайн

Вынужден рыскать иконки вскрывая другие приложения. Надоело. Может есть какой-то ресурс где можно скачать одним архивом огромную кучу иконок? Желательно уже рассортированную по папкам `mdpi`, `hdpi`, `x-xx-xxxhdpi`.

Иконок из Google Material Icon Library мне мало. Популярные сайты не дают скачать бесплатно паки. Только по одному. Что можно придумать? Те, у кого с этим проблем нет - поделитесь ссылочками :)

**UPD**

Только Material Design

Comment: Что, если [так](http://www.yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=material%20design%20icons)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть ресурсы с бесплатными иконками, такие как [iconfinder.com](https://www.iconfinder.com) (есть секция FREE) или [graphicburger.com](http://graphicburger.com/icons-set/) (лицензия ресурса разрешает свободное коммерческое и индивидуальное использование)

Так же довольно большой ресурс по векторным иконкам [flaticon.com](http://www.flaticon.com), которые с недавнего времени удобнее и предпочтительнее использовать в Android-приложении. Распространяется по [лицензии FBL](http://file000.flaticon.com/downloads/license/license.pdf), в общем то они бесплатные.

Answer (score 3):

[Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Main_Page) - не то чтобы огромный, но достаточно большой набор различных public иконок.

Например, известный набор иконок [Crystal Clear](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Crystal_Clear?uselang=ru)

Свободные не означает, что с ними можно делать все что угодно. Например, Crystal Clear лицензирован под [GNU LGPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Lesser_General_Public_License?uselang=ru).

Answer (score 3):

http://www.fatcow.com/free-icons

Стиль достаточно старый, но зато 3000+ иконок

Answer (score 1):

Есть ещё http://fontawesome.io там много иконок, в шрифтовом формате, на все случаи жизни.